# Load a new file in JSP

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, maven

I have a web app use Eclipse, Spring MVC to create a new XML file and then use XSLT to transform it in JSP page. And my problem is after creating XML file, JSP page cannot find it. If I debug and go to the Project explorer in eclipse after the XML file are created and do refresh, JSP page will find it extractly. So I think I need to create XML file in build folder but I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to put your newly created XML file in your WEB_INF folder, you could be more organized, and secure .. but just by putting your xml file in WEB_INF folder will give you access to the file from your JSP in my view